# How to check if 2 routes share a path

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps

I have 2 routes, routes `A to B` and `C to D` on google maps. Now route `C to D` share the same street/path with route `A to B`. How do I check if one is on the polyline of the other?

For example: [C to D is on A to B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvieC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Geometry Library's poly](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#poly) namespace which contains utility functions that determine whether a given point is inside or near a polygon or polyline.

Use [`isLocationOnEdge(point:LatLng, poly:Polygon|Polyline, tolerance?:number)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge) method to determine whether a point falls on or near a polyline, or on or near the edge of a polygon. You need to pass the point, the polyline/polygon, and optionally a tolerance value in degrees to `google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge()` then the function returns true if the distance between the point and the closest point on the line or edge falls within the specified tolerance.

Example:

```
function initialize() {
  var myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(46.0, -125.9);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: myPosition,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      mapOptions);

  var cascadiaFault = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [
      new google.maps.LatLng(49.95, -128.1),
      new google.maps.LatLng(46.26, -126.3),
      new google.maps.LatLng(40.3, -125.4)
    ]
  });

  cascadiaFault.setMap(map);

  if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(myPosition, cascadiaFault, 10e-1)) {
    alert("Relocate!");
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

You can also check these [examples](https://github.com/search?l=javascript&q=isLocationOnEdge%28point%3ALatLng%2C+poly%3APolygon%7CPolyline%2C+tolerance%3F%3Anumber&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) on GitHub.